# Reduce a sequence of items provided by a generator in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, generator, reduce

Say I have a sequence of items and I want to perform a reduce operation via `myReducer` function (whatever it is). If my items are in an array (say `myArray`), it's easy:

```
myArray.reduce(myReducer);
```

What if, however, my sequence is quite large and I don't want to allocate an array of all of it, only to immediately reduce it item after item? I can create a generator function for my sequence, that part is clear. Is there a straightforward way of how to then perform the reduction? I mean apart from writing the reduce functionality for a generator myself.

Comment: You need to create a lazy evaluation array object/class with a lazy evaluation reduce.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

For now, ECMA-Script standard provides functions like `reduce` for arrays, so you're out of luck: you need to implement your own `reduce` for *iterables*:

```js
const reduce = (f, i, it) => {
  let o = i

  for (let x of it)
    o = f (o, x)

  return o
}

const xs = [1, 2, 3]

const xs_ = {
  [Symbol.iterator]: function* () {
    yield 1
    yield 2
    yield 3
  }
}

const output1 = reduce ((o, x) => o + x, 10, xs)
const output2 = reduce ((o, x) => o + x, 10, xs_)

console.log ('output1:', output1)
console.log ('output2:', output2)
```

Comment: What's the problem with my answer? The answer is there's no current native way of reducing, mapping, filtering, ... iterables.

Comment: it´s a nice solution! +1

Comment: @MatíasFidemraizer: Thanks, that's what I thought. I'm just not as up-to-date with the current state of EcmaScript, so I asked to be sure that I'm not reinventing the wheel.

Comment: I tried myself the Symbol.iterator way, that is giving you what you wanted, unfortunatelly I was not able to transform it so it would work with the native reduce.

Comment: @MatíasFidemraizer I don't see any difference with `xs.reduce((o, x) => (o + x), 10)` or with `Array.prototype.call(xs, (o, x) => (o + x), 10)` if it is array like.  That doesn't seem to answer the question.

Comment: @DominiqueFortin There's a very important difference: my proposed `reduce` works on iterables (i.e. any instance which implements the iterator protocol)

Comment: @Ondra No problem! :-) Sometimes the solution is just that yours is right!

Comment: @DominiqueFortin See my edited answer. There's a demonstration of this `reduce` with even an iterator provided by a generator.

Comment: @MatíasFidemraizer Thanks.  I'll brush up on iterables.

Comment: @DominiqueFortin You're welcome! It's an interesting topic, and once you get the idea, you'll be stuck like the OP and the rest of us: `filter`, `map`, ... should be available to iterables. The issue is *how* you do that: it should need some kind of black magic, because the whole functions should be available if there's a `Symbol.iterator` symbol!

Comment: For bonus points, you could have your `reduce` itself be a generator function that reduces however far into the original generator you want.